# React Rerender component not working, Cannot read property 'forceUpdate' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

How do I get forceUpdate() working to rerender component? I receive the following error, Cannot read property 'forceUpdate' of undefined

```
function App() {

  const renderData = () => {
    console.log('render');
    this.forceUpdate();
  }

  return (
    <div>
      Test
      <button onClick={renderData}> render data </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Error:**

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'forceUpdate' of undefined

```
const renderData = () => {
console.log('render');
this.forceUpdate();
```

Resource: [Can you force a React component to rerender without calling setState?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30626030/can-you-force-a-react-component-to-rerender-without-calling-setstate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.forceUpdate()` is only available in [class based components](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)

You can force an update by updating the state:

```js
const [someVar, setSomeVar] = useState(null);

const renderData = () => {
    console.log('render');
    setSomeVar(true);
}
```

Or taking inspiration from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53837442/522330), create your own forceUpdate function:

```
function useForceUpdate(){
    const [value, setValue] = useState(0); // integer state
    return () => setValue(value => value + 1); // update the state to force render
}
```

I would strongly suggest not to do this, this is a sign that you should probably structure your logic differently.